# Install4j Windows Gui app does not create log file

Tags: install4j

## Problem

"Windows Archive" generates log file and "Windows" not.

## Setup

I'm using install4j to generate a windows gui application. I only have one launcher and redirected `stderr` and `stdout`.

Then I create two media files: "Windows" and "Windows Archive".

If I use the "windows archive" type the log files are created and filed with content.
If I use the "windows" type the log files are not created.

I know that in both cases the same error happened, so there should be the same output in both cases.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the log files writable? If not, you have to specify a location where they can be written such as ${installer:sys.localAppdataDir}\mystderr.log

Comment: @IngoKegel Yeah, that worked. Thanks . If you provide an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the redirection files are not writable, you have to specify a location where they can be written such as

```
${installer:sys.localAppdataDir}\mystderr.log
```

Redirection files for generated launchers are configured on the "Executable info->Redirection" step of the launcher wizard.